# Can I detect when user enter on my website by direct link or with react-router?

Tags: javascript, react-router, html5-history

In my current project, I must to implement different site behavior depending on whether it was a visit by a direct link or a redirect from a another pages of site trough a react-router.

So... is there a way to detect this fact?

Comment: @josemartindev this is one of variants, but in a "already has answers" link guys sayd that  documen.referer work not always. Thanks for your answer, I appreciated them, but that's not the whole answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.referrer`. The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link). Here is an example using React Hooks.

```
useEffect(() => { 
  if (document.referrer === "") { 
     console.log("User came directly"); 
  } else { 
     console.log("User did not came directly"); 
  } 
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not 100% reliable. Take this advice with a grain of salt